# Flask webapp errors out when deploying to google cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Semantic Similarity application which uses tensorflow_hub models. However I keep getting this error and I don't see any documentation for the specific error "Flask has no attribute server"

app.yaml file

```
runtime: python38

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static



entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 120
instance_class: F4_1G
```

Main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, jsonify, request
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')


@app.route('/')
def menu():
    return render_template("index.html")


def semantic(search1, search2):
    comparison = model([search1, search2])
    return np.inner(comparison[0], comparison[1])


@app.route('/<search1>/<search2>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def deploy(search1, search2):
    compare = semantic(search1, search2)
    compare = compare*100
    compare = str(compare)
    compare = compare.strip("")
    response = {
        "Semantic Similarity": compare
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return make_response(jsonify(response), 200)
    else:
        return render_template("results.html", compare=compare)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Requirement.txt file

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
gunicorn==19.10.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
numpy==1.16.6
tensorflow-estimator==2.0.0
tensorflow-hub==0.8.0
absl-py==0.9.0
tensorflow==2.0.0
```

There is also a static folder which has a css file and a template file including 2 html files which I don't think contribute to the error.

This is the error that occurs when I run

> gcloud app deploy

```
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py"
, line 586, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in init_p
rocess      self.load_wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.
app.wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/env/lib
/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/g
unicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 361, in import_app      app = eval(obj, vars(mod))    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  AttributeError: 'Flask' object has n
o attribute 'server'
```

Comment: Can you share your requirements.txt file?

Comment: Yup, sharing it now

Comment: Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1 release date is january 2017, Not sure about its compliance with python 3.8. Did it work locally with python 3.8?

Comment: Error still persists when I remove the requirement of flask-bootstrap, I realized I didn't really use it and just converted it to regular bootstrap imports on the templates